# Synonymize [restful-url] -> [rest]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

From the wiki excerpts, I don't see any difference between [restful-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restful-url) and [rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rest).

Comment: On a closer inspection, [tag:restful-url] appears to be more about how to organize URL structure for REST services, the wiki just doesn't reflect this.

Comment: I think they're close enough to be synonyms. We might want to throw [\[restful-architecture\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restful-architecture) in there as well.

Comment: I, personally, have strong feelings against restful-url. Can a URL/URI be restful? or not be restful at all? REST systems shouldn't care about the characters used within a URI as long as they don't violate [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986). The whole URI is a pointer to some resource and partial segments don't state a parent/child relationship on these segments actually. Most of the question tagged with restful-url or api-design are opinionated anyway and don't really tackle REST also. So I don't see a need for it actually

Comment: @RomanVottner I think we [should we put `restful-url` to rest](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376362/1426227).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of synonymizing [restful-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restful-url) with [rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rest) I am in favor of [burniating this tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376362/should-we-put-restful-url-to-rest) instead and replace it with [url-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-design) as most questions tagged with [restful-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restful-url) are asking for which URI expresses the designers intent the best.

In a through and through REST architecture clients shouldn't care about the URI/URL at all as it will ship with an accompanying link relation name expressing the intent of it and a client should base its decision whether to invoke the URI on that link-relation name. Even Fielding himself claimed that [most of the design effort should be put into defining/designin media-types and meaningful link-relation names instead of overengineering URIs](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven). Further, the URI itself is just a pointer as a whole. There is no automatic parent-child relationship involved in the structure of the URI. Multiple URIs, however, can form a tree that may seem like a parent-child relationship though.

The idea behind this approach is clearly to allow the server to change its internal structure any time it wants. Clients interpreting, or even hardcoding, such URIs will have a hard time with interacting with such an API further, while clients invoking just the URI related to a certain meaningful link-relation name will have no problems with such changes.

As already claimed in my comment an URI remains an URI regardless if it is used in a REST API or not. There is therefore no such thing as a RESTful-URL or NON-RESTful-URL IMO, hence my support to burniate this tag.

Comment: +1: I definitely support this idea.